# Adding video to youtube watch history

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to insert a video into my Youtube watch history

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key={my_api_key}&access_token={my_access_token}

POST data:
{
"snippet": {
"playlistId": "watch_history_playlist_id",
"resourceId": {
  "videoId": "video_id",
   "kind": "youtube#video"
}
}
}
```

and I am getting 403 Forbidden with error : You do not have permission to execute this method.

```
{
    "error": {
       "errors": [
           {
            "domain": "youtube.common",
            "reason": "forbidden",
            "message": "Forbidden"
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
}
```

I have tried inserting in other playlists and it is working fine, but the watch history insertion is not working correctly, I found another question in stack overflow but the solution is not working any more.

Comment: Playlists are fine to be created, but not Video in History. Youtube History only input video in the list when you watch the video.

Comment: @brian-s I do not creating video in history playlist, i am just adding videoid. It is work fine with other native playlists as liked, watch later or favorites, but not history.

Comment: You can't insert video into history, those are automatically inserted after watching, how are you even doing that? That you get that error? :)

Comment: @brian-s When i watched video in my app, it was do not inserted to watch history.

Comment: Its an app related issue, now is this third party app or actual youtube app? And what Device or OS?

Comment: @brian-s i am testing this request here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#try-it

Comment: Well those API calls are only for Playlist, not inserting video to History, i doubt you can insert video into history, that is Youtube privilege boundary that either use some type of sessions or cookies function to read YOUR history and send it to there database. If they did allow API calls to history, you can easy inject stuff and hack the site. @RenDishen

Comment: @brian-s But if we will look to list of native playlists we can see playlist watch history. And what a difference between adding video ID to watch later playlist and watch history? Its just list of videos IDs and cant be used to hack the site.

Comment: Watch later playlist have different privileges as well @RenDishen

Comment: Are you also authorizing your calls? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication